# Angular 1.5 angular-ui-router respond to custom url hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash, dojo, angular-ui-router

I have a specific use case;

- Angular child application running independently within a larger dojo based host application.
- Hash based routing in the dojo host application
- Requirement for hash based routing rather than html5 history api
- Requirement for routing within Angular child application.
- Requirement for Angular child application to use and react to *only* the portion of the hash after a colon delimiter

Example url:

`domain.com/my/page#myDojoHash:my/ui/router/hash/path`

Current example ui-router state:

```
$stateProvider
    .state({
        name: 'index',
        url: '/{dojoHash:.+:}my/ui/router/hash/path',
        template: homeTemplate
})
```

In this case dojo works fine, as I can parse out the first part of the url using regex.

Ui-router is also able to load pages.

My question is how can I make ui-router react to changes in the second part of the hash only? Specifically, when the dojo application changes the hash how can I prevent the angular app from reacting?

Is it possible to hook in to the hash change event for ui-router, test the hash using a regex and react, or not, accordingly?